# Nested namespace for cleaner code

Tags: c++, namespaces, coding-style, naming

I am currently writing an adapter to convert types between two frameworks A <-> B. I have a little bit of trouble with the names, as they are getting quite long and unreadable in my opinion. I then decided to use namespaces in a quite nested way, I have seen rarely anywhere else.

OLD:

```
TypeA mylib::cvtToAtype(TypeB) {}
TypeB mylib::cvtToBtype(TypeA) {}
```

NEW:

```
TypeA mylib::cvt::to_a::type(TypeB) {}
TypeB mylib::cvt::to_b::type(TypeA) {}
```

Would you consider this a good style or do you see heavy downsides? I think it looks quite clean, however it can be really misused if someone decides to "use namespaces". Then type is not really a unique name to identify what the function is doing. Additionally a namespace called "cvt" might also not be super unique.

What do you think?

Comment: It depends on your needs, There's no drawback to make logical complexities in C++.

Comment: If there is one thing I really dislike, it is deeply nested namespaces being used as architectural devices.

Comment: *"as they are getting quite long and unreadable in my opinion."*, `cvtToAtype`is shorter than `cvt::to_a::type`. Camel case vs "namespace" case -> same readability (and if using namespace is used, it might simplify reading, but current names seems poor)...

Comment: @Jarod42: Jeah okay, I kind of misuse the benefits of underscore readability here for my camelCase. But can’t shift all the stuff to underscore now. Especially as I am cool with it in all other parts of the code. Only these converters produce so annoying names :D

Comment: @Neil: Hmm, what do you say to: TypeA cvt_to_A::type(TypeB) {}? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you started with:

```
TypeA mylib::cvtToAtype(TypeB) {}
TypeB mylib::cvtToBtype(TypeA) {}
```

Your stated problem: function names *"getting quite long and unreadable"*.  You propose:

```
mylib::cvt::to_a::type
```

Firstly, "cvt" is not going to be painlessly recognised as "convert" by readers/maintainers of your code.  The trailing `::type` seems pointless to me.  Anything called "to_" can be expected to be a conversion, so I don't see the point in the `::cvt::` level.

For whatever it's worth, some alternatives...

#### Constructors

You could consider creating constructors `[explicit] TypeA::TypeA(TypeB)` and `[explicit] TypeB::TypeB(TypeA)` so the client usage is simply:

```
TypeA a{b};
functionThatWantsB(TypeB{a});
```

#### Cast/conversion template

If you want to keep the functions separate from the TypeA/B classes, a "cast" style template with specialisations is a nice option:

```
template <typename TypeTo, typename TypeFrom>
TypeTo convert(const TypeFrom&);

template <>
TypeB convert<TypeB, TypeA>(const TypeA& a) { return TypeB{...}; }

template <>
TypeA convert<TypeA, TypeB>(const TypeB& a) { return TypeA{...}; }
```

Client usage is then the familiar casting notation: e.g. `convert<TypeB>(a)`.  This is considerably more powerful than `cvtToAtype` because if the destination type is abstract - a parameter in a template, an alias from `using` or `typedef` - you can still cast.

#### Knowing the destination type because it's a function argument

Another option is to have a function argument of the convert-to type, so the caller doesn't have to type it out as part of the conversion function name or a template parameter:

```
TypeA& loadFrom(TypeA&, const TypeB&) { ... }
TypeB& loadFrom(TypeB&, const TypeA&) { ... }
```

Such use of the compile-time polymorphism of overloads means the conversion code doesn't need to be updated every time the variables involved change between supported types.